# Calculating time difference and rounding in VBA for access

Tags: vba, ms-access

**Problem:**
I am designing a ticket system and we need to track time spent on a task. We have a start time and end time which is a date/time field. I need to calculate the time spent from these two fields and then round it to the nearest hour always rounding up. 121 minutes should be counted as 3 hours.

**My attempt:**
Currently i am converting the time between the start and end time to minutes and then trying to round that to nearest hour.

Mins field i have is `=DateDiff("n",[starttime],[endtime])`

total time field i have is `Me.TotalTime.Value = mins mod 60 + 1`
This works unless the minutes is exactly 60, 120, 180 etc...

any solution is appreciated

Comment: Something like so `int(181/60) + iif(181 mod 60>0,1,0)` for 181 minutes or a little simpler `int(181/60) + cint(181 mod 60)`

Comment: sorry ignore the 2nd idea, I cant edit to update it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it directly:

```
 Hours = Hour(TimeSerial(Hour([EndTime] - [StartTime]), -Int(-Minute([EndTime] - [StartTime]) / 60) * 60, 0))
```